# Error when using WPF OpenFileDialog more than once

Tags: .net, wpf, openfiledialog

In my wpf application I need a button which lets me select a file from my local system and upload it.
When I click the button for the first time and upload there is no problem; from the second onwards, there is this pop-up message box which displays

> You can’t open this location using this program.
>   Please try a different location. openfiledialog

I can close that message and select my file.
But why is this appearing anyway?

Comment: You should edit your question showing us some code...

Comment: You can look there: [OpenFileDialog default path][1]
Check hes code, maybe it can help?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980262/openfiledialog-default-path

Comment: Hi mlemay, thanks a lot for the example shown. I have realised the place of the problem. I am passing a string to the initiladirectory which has the lastopenenddfile's path. hence the directory is trying to open the file and hence showing the above message. I truncated the filepath to get the folder path and assigned it to the initialdirectory. Now working fine..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am passing a string to the initialdirectory property which has the lastopenenddfile's path. hence the directory is trying to open the file and hence showing the above message. I truncated the filepath to get the folder path and assigned it to the initialdirectory. Now working fine..

Comment: If this is the solution to your question, please mark the answer as accepted, to improve your accept rating.