# Form type "file" default folder

Tags: winapi, vb6, registry, webbrowser-control

I have a webform displayed in a WebBrowser control in a Visual Basic application to allow users to upload files to my webserver. Unusually for this type of thing, I know in advance the folder they need to browse to (I want them to upload a file which the VB application has generated) and I would like the Browse dialog box to default to that folder but it seems to default to whichever folder was last used by any application for File / Open.

I've tried using ChDir in VB to set the current folder but that doesn't work.

Is there any way I can persuade the Browse box to default to my desired folder?

Comment: This question should help you - http://stackoverflow.com/q/9980262/17776

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I ought to state that there is no reliable way of doing this. The reason why it is so hard is for security reasons. There is a `defaultValue` and `value` property for the `INPUT TYPE=FILE` element, but if programmers had access to this, this could be used to suck files from the client machine - definitely not a good idea.

In Internet Explorer, the browse file dialogue is actually implemented by a Windows Common Dialog component. However, you have no direct access to this component.

There is no reliable browser-independent way of doing this. And I certainly don't recommend you reverse-engineer the "Last Recently Used" file list for the Common Dialog control (see jac's link). Doing that is very dangerous, since it is an internal-algorithm likely to change. And worse, you are hacking global state to solve a local problem (see [Old New Thing blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/11/9193695.aspx), ad nauseam).

A solution that doesn't violate global state, but still hacky is to take advantage of the fact we know what the text is on the file upload dialogue. After your document has loaded, you can use a Timer to wait for the dialogue to appear, and at that point, paste the correct directory into the dialogue.

In my sample, I have code where the web browser control sits, and the BrowserHack.bas module.

Form code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdLoadPage_Click()
    ' Store the default path into the .Tag property.
    tmrWaitForDialogue.Tag = "C:\Windows\System32"

    ' Load URL.
    wbMain.Navigate "<URL>"
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    tmrWaitForDialogue.Enabled = False
    tmrWaitForDialogue.Interval = 100 ' 10th of a second delay.
End Sub

Private Sub tmrWaitForDialogue_Timer()
    If BrowserHack.IsBrowserFileDialogueVisible Then
        ' We don't want the Timer to fire again.
        tmrWaitForDialogue.Enabled = False

        ' Copy the directory onto the clipboard.
        Clipboard.Clear
        Clipboard.SetText tmrWaitForDialogue.Tag

        ' The focus will be on the file path text box in the Open dialogue.
        ' Use CTL-V to paste the text, and then followed by an Enter character to
        ' dismiss the dropdown, and another to Open the folder.
        SendKeys "^V"
        SendKeys "{ENTER}"
        SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub wbMain_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
    tmrWaitForDialogue.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

BrowserHack:

```
' Purpose:  Code to look for the WebBrowser (Internet Explorer) dialogue which appears when a File Upload control is clicked.
' Notes:    Internet Explorer version dependent.

Option Explicit

Private Declare Function EnumThreadWindows Lib "User32.dll" ( _
    ByVal dwThreadId As Long, _
    ByVal lpfn As Long, _
    ByVal lParam As Long _
) As Long

Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "User32.dll" Alias "GetClassNameW" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As Long, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "User32.dll" Alias "GetWindowTextW" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As Long, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function IsWindowVisible Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long

Private Const APITRUE                       As Long = 1 ' Win32 API TRUE value
Private Const APIFALSE                      As Long = 0 ' Win32 API FALSE value

' This dialogue class is pretty universal.
Private Const m_ksDialogueClass             As String = "#32770"
Private Const m_knDialogueClassLen          As Long = 6

' This text may well change every time the browser is updated.
Private Const m_ksDialogueText              As String = "Choose File to Upload"
Private Const m_knDialogueTextLen           As Long = 21

' Buffers to be used for these strings.
Private m_sClassNameBuffer                  As String
Private m_sWindowNameBuffer                 As String

' Callback from the EnumThreadWindow() function.
Private Function EnumThreadWndProc( _
    ByVal hWnd As Long, _
    ByVal lParam As Long _
) As Long

    Dim nRet            As Long

    ' Filter out hidden windows.
    If IsWindowVisible(hWnd) = APITRUE Then

        ' Retrieve the class name of the window.
        ' Note that this function requires you to allocate a buffer *including* the terminating null character.
        ' Since VB strings *always* are null terminated, we can add one to the string length.
        nRet = GetClassName(hWnd, StrPtr(m_sClassNameBuffer), (m_knDialogueClassLen + 1))

        ' If the classes match, then try for a match on the window's text.
        If m_sClassNameBuffer = m_ksDialogueClass Then
            ' Ditto GetClassName().
            nRet = GetWindowText(hWnd, StrPtr(m_sWindowNameBuffer), (m_knDialogueTextLen + 1))
            If m_sWindowNameBuffer = m_ksDialogueText Then
                ' This return value says "stop the enumeration".
                ' In this case EnumThreadWindow() with also return APIFALSE.
                EnumThreadWndProc = APIFALSE
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    End If

    EnumThreadWndProc = APITRUE

End Function

' Purpose:  If the browser window is detected
Public Function IsBrowserFileDialogueVisible() As Boolean

    ' If this is the first time this function has been called, the buffers will not be allocated.
    ' Do this now.
    If LenB(m_sClassNameBuffer) = 0 Then
        m_sClassNameBuffer = Space$(m_knDialogueClassLen)
        m_sWindowNameBuffer = Space$(m_knDialogueTextLen)
    End If

    ' Enumerate through all windows on this thread. VB apps are single-threaded, and all GUI elements are forced to be on this thread, so this is ok.
    If EnumThreadWindows(App.ThreadID, AddressOf EnumThreadWndProc, 0&) = APIFALSE Then
        IsBrowserFileDialogueVisible = True
    Else
        IsBrowserFileDialogueVisible = False
    End If

End Function
```