# OpenFileDialog set complete path

Tags: vb.net

```
        Dim streamf As System.IO.Stream
        Dim stringf As String
        stringf = OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString()
        streamf = OpenFileDialog1.OpenFile()
```

I have a file ScreenShot.png attached on the application installation path which means if user run the .exe file from Desktop it will store ScreenShot.png on his desktop and so on.

Now i need to get the full path to that ScreenShot.png file to be sent in the FAX

```
    Dim srcBt As Byte()
    Dim encodedBase64 As String
    Dim filereader As New IO.FileStream(stringf, IO.FileMode.Open)

    ReDim srcBt(filereader.Length)
    filereader.Read(srcBt, 0, filereader.Length)
    filereader.Close()

    encodedBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(srcBt)
```

So the problem part is how can i put that location of the file to the Stringf ? Because example i have force user to locate the file using OpenFileDialog and i have predefined file

Comment: This link will be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980262/openfiledialog-default-path

Answer (score 0):

This should convert any (relative) path to an absolut path:

```
Dim stringf_info As New System.IO.FileInfo(stringf)
stringf = stringf_info.FullName
```